# Link directory to another directory to ccopy files

Tags: symbolic-link, cp

I have a folder:

```
/share/public
```

I am working in the folder:

```
/home/john/workingfolder
```

It means that currently I am in the "workingfolder".

I would like to send files to /share/public but faster like this:

Create something in "workingfloder" and copy files to that something:

```
cp pixel.c somethingidontknow
```

And the file pixel.c is copied to /share/public

Or:

```
pixel.c > somethingidontknow
```

It is faster than typing:

cp pixel.c /share/public

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `alias`:

```bash
alias cp2p="cp -t /share/public"
```

(`p` for "public")

You can put the `alias` to your `.bashrc` to make it permanent. And of course you can name the `alias` different...

Then you can run:

```
cp2p FILE
```

or

```
cp2p FILE1 FILE2 ...
```